How should I determine if $x(t)$ is odd or even?
Homework problem:

Consider the differential equation
$$
\ddot{x}+x+\epsilon(\alpha x^2\operatorname{sgn}(x)+\beta x^3)=0, 
$$
$0<\epsilon\ll1,\; \alpha>0,\; \beta>0$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants, and the signum function is defined by
$$
\operatorname{sgn}(x) = \begin{cases}
\phantom{-}1 &\text{for } x>0, \\
\phantom{-}0 &\text{for } x=0, \\
-1&\text{for } x<0. 
\end{cases}
$$
Show that all the phase curves are invariant under reflections in both the $x$-axis and the $\dot{x}$-axis of the phase diagram. (You don't need to provide the phase diagram.)

To provide this proof, I think I need to first determine whether $x(t)$ is odd or even and then, look at the symmetry properties of the phase curves. But how should I find $x(t)$ in the beginning? I've already showed that all solutions of the equation are bounded and periodic by first finding the potential energy $V(x)$ of the given system and finding that the stationary (fixed) point is a stable center (not asymptotically stable). Should I use the perturbation theory/method to find $x(t)$ first?

Note: Since $x\operatorname{sgn}(x) = |x|$, the equation can be rewritten as
$$
\ddot{x} + x\bigl( 1 + \varepsilon(\alpha|x| + \beta x^2) \bigr) = 0.
$$

Hint: Note that $H(x,\dot{x}) = \frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2 + \epsilon \int_0^x \alpha y|y| + \beta y^3~\mathrm{d}y$ is a conserved quantity. What can you say about level curves of this function subject to these reflections?

That they are symmetric, probably? But what should I do in order to analyze these level curves of this Hamiltonian function?

Let $y=\dot{x}$ and then the equation becomes
$$\begin{cases}
\dot{x}=y, \\
\dot{y}=-x-\epsilon(\alpha x^2\operatorname{sgn}(x)+\beta x^3).
\end{cases}\tag1$$
Clearly (1) is invariant under $(x,y)\to (-x,-y)$; namely all the phase curves are invariant under reflections in both the $x$-axis and the $\dot{x}$-axis of the phase diagram.

Thank you very much!
